# SQL Server : multiple autoincrement on one column

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

There is a table as follow:

```
Id   ||  ParentId ||  Other Columns ... 
=======================================
1    ||  1        || ...
2    ||  1        || ...
3    ||  1        || ...
1    ||  2        || ...
2    ||  2        || ...
3    ||  2        || ...
1    ||  3        || ...
2    ||  3        || ...
```

Column `[Id]` must have autoincremented value based on `[ParentId]` (own numeration).

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: get and set rowcount to particular column

Comment: i need to lock table in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parentId order by <any other column>) ID,
ParentId,<other columns>  
from  yourtable
```

edit1:

If you want the id to be used in the where clause

```
with cte as(                                
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parentId order by <any other column>) ID,
ParentId,<other columns>  
from  yourtable)
select * from cte where ID=(some value)
```

Comment: i need to use `Id` and `ParentId` as complex key in future. so, it will not working if i delete some rows

Comment: @BobSponge: then you can enclose the query in a Common table expression

Comment: numeration will be broken if i delete rows

Comment: @BobSponge: when you run the same query again after delete, it will be ordered properly .

Comment: @JoeGJoseph numeration must be same after deleting. for example, i have ids 1, 2 and 3. i deleting row with id=2 and in table must stay rows with id 1 and 3. next inserted row will have id 4 (for same `ParentId`).

Comment: @BobSponge: You mean, when you insert a row in the table the Id column should automatically increment based on parentID?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph rows with same `ParentId` must have own autoincremented numeration

Answer (score 0):

Demo

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32645/6

Updated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32645/13

```
create table dummy(parentId int)

insert into dummy values(1)
insert into dummy values(1)
insert into dummy values(2)
insert into dummy values(1)
insert into dummy values(4)
insert into dummy values(4)
insert into dummy values(5)
insert into dummy values(1)

select row_number() over (order by parentID) as ID,parentID from dummy
```

Comment: The OP has asked to get the ID values based on the pattern of ParentID column .Your query will simply print the number of rows